# Nutch and Elasticsearch 1.1.1

Tags: java, elasticsearch, search-engine, nutch

I am using Elasticsearch 1.1.1 and trying to get Nutch working with it. I have tried both version 1.8 and 2.2.1. When I finish running the crawl, I get this for final results:

```
...
Indexer: starting at 2014-06-13 00:14:33
Indexer: deleting gone documents: false
Indexer: URL filtering: false
Indexer: URL normalizing: false
Active IndexWriters :
ElasticIndexWriter
elastic.cluster : elastic prefix cluster
elastic.host : hostname
elastic.port : port
elastic.index : elastic index command 
elastic.max.bulk.docs : elastic bulk index doc counts. (default 250) 
elastic.max.bulk.size : elastic bulk index length. (default 2500500 ~2.5MB)


Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1357)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:114)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:176)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:186)
```

I have updated the ivy.xml file for the new version, and tried every variation of things I can figure out from various tutorials and posts on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trunk contains a patch https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1745 which has been committed and will be in Nutch-1.9. It should fix your problem - although the message you posted doesn't help determining what the issue actually is.

BTW you'd get a more relevant audience by posting on the [Nutch user list](http://nutch.apache.org/mailing_lists.html)

Comment: I downloaded Nutch-1.9 directly from SVN being that it isn't complete yet. Seems to be working perfectly for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well, and turned out that the indexer plugin `indexer-elastic` was still configured to use an old version of elasticsearch as a dependency in `src\plugin\indexer-elastic\ivy.xml`